# Bad Request in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

When I want to insert an image in Joomla, the following error occurs:

> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>   Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_hive/5.0 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_fcgid/2.3.6 Server at www.example.com Port 443

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming your `.htaccess` file to `.htaccess.old` and see if that fixes the problem. If it doesn't, then try disabling all non-core system plugins and see if that fixes the problem. If it doesn't, then make sure the settings in your `configuration.php` file are all correct, if they are, then check your server logs for any clue about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SEF urls have been enabld in global configuration without renaming the file htaccess.txt to .htaccess

Wither rename the file or disable SEF urls